# How to change value of variable from a different .py file in Python

Tags: python, scope

From a file **foo.py**, I want to change the value of a variable which's placed in a different file, let's say **bar.py**.

I've tried to do it importing the variable, but it seems that it's imported not as reference.

Just examples:

**bar.py**:

```
age = 18
```

**foo.py**:

```
from bar import age

def changeAge(age, newAge):
    age = newAge

changeAge(age, 19)
```

I've also tried to pass `age` as parameter from **bar.py**, but same result, it's not passed by reference so its value is not changed.

**bar.py**:

```
from foo import changeAge

age = 18

changeAge(age, 19)
```

As I said, it didn't work at all. I know I can reach this returning the var from the function, but it will probable make me to change a lot of code and, why not, I want to know if there is a way to do what I need, I'm still a beginner in Python. Another way is to wrapper the variable in an object, a list or something like that, but it doesn't seem too elegant.

Comment: Not possible. Take a look at this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/3122880)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def changeAge(newAge):
    import bar
    bar.age = newAge
```

Comment: It works perfectly but what is the down side or the drawbacks of importing a full file?

Comment: in terms of performance, it requires parsing that file (and any other modules imported in that file). in terms of symbol table, it creates only a `bar` symbol, and it does so in the scope of the `changeAge` function, so it will not affect the global symbol table

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change the value of 'age' you can do the following

**bar.py**

```
age = 18
```

**foo.py**

```
import bar

def changeAge(newAge):
    bar.age = newAge

changeAge(19)
```

Answer (score -3):

You forgot to return newAge.

```
from bar import age

def changeAge(age, newAge):
    age = newAge
    return newAge

print changeAge(age, 19)
```

Prints out 19 as expected.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to return values.

Comment: My bad, I haven't read carefully. In this case try `bar.age` instead the plain age, should work.